# Javascript Equals to gets highlighted in if statement

Tags: javascript

So i was making a pretty simple carousel in which when a user clicks on a button, the image or content changes. I got it to work halfway but i am only one problem. In the code i first check if the display of card1 is block and the display of card3 is none. That is where it shows the problem. In the first part it is fine but after the && when i write `card3.style = "display:none"` it highlights the equals to sign and doesn't work. I have tried changing the orientation of the code and even adding `==`but to no avail. Can someone help me with this?

You can checkout my code:

```
   <div class="card1" id="card1">
        
    </div>

    <div class="card2" id="card2">
        
    </div>

    <div class="card3" id="card3">
        
    </div>

    <button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

```
.card1{
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.card2{
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
}
.card3{
    display: none;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```
var card1 = document.getElementById("card1")
var card2 = document.getElementById("card2")
var card3 = document.getElementById("card3")

function change(){
    if(card1.style = 'display:block;' && card3.style = 'display:none'){
        card1.style = 'display:none';
        card2.style = 'display:block';
    
    }
    

}
```

Comment: You could try `card1.style.display === 'block'`? Also `=` means assignment not comparison.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` to compare:

```js
var card1 = document.getElementById("card1")
var card2 = document.getElementById("card2")
var card3 = document.getElementById("card3")

function change(){
    if(card1.style.display == 'block' && card3.style.display == 'none'){
        card1.style = 'display:none';
        card2.style = 'display:block';
    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work

Comment: @MohammedHassan Are you hiding the cards inline?

Comment: hold on i will leave some of my html and css

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` operator and update `card1.style` to `card1.style.display`.

```js
var card1 = document.getElementById("card1");
var card2 = document.getElementById("card2");
var card3 = document.getElementById("card3");

function change() {
  if (card1.style.display == 'block' && card3.style.display == 'none') {
    card1.style = 'display:none';
    card2.style = 'display:block';
  }
}
```

```css
.card1 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.card2 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: red;
}

.card3 {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card1" id="card1" style="display: block;">
  Card 1
</div>

<div class="card2" id="card2" style="display: none;">
  Card 2
</div>

<div class="card3" id="card3" style="display: none;">
  Card 3
</div>

<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Comment: it is still doesn't change the cards

Comment: @MohammedHassan I see your problem. `card1.style.display` just can get the style in the HTML (style attribute). It can't get the style in the CSS file. So you must move the `display` property to HTML. I updated my demo to let it works.